# Como limitar el ancho de banda en cuenta ftp en un servidor web ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Hola amigos disculpa en mi servidor web linux en ubuntu  como podria limitar el ancho a  cuentas ftp de a mis cliente estuve  investigando pero ningúno me funciona ,como podria limitar la subida,porque necesito esto?bueno cada tiene contrata un plan del espacio y velocidad necesaria para su cuenta pero nose como podria hacer eso?

Answer (score 2):

Si utilizas Proftpd, podrías configurar `TransferRate` en tu fichero `/etc/proftpd.conf` tal y como se indica en la siguiente referencia:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-to-limit-ftp-speed

y en la documentación oficial:

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_TransferRate.html

Por ejemplo:

```
TransferRate APPE,RETR,STOR 100
```

Y recuerda que tendrias que reiniciar el servicio para que se apliquen los cambios:

```
/etc/init.d/proftpd restart
```

Todo esto funciona bajo el modulo `mod_xfer` : 
http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_xfer.html